# Writing piece-wise functions in TensorFlow / if then in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I write a piece-wise TensorFlow function i.e. a function that has an if-statement inside it?

Current code

```
import tensorflow as tf

my_fn = lambda x : x ** 2 if x > 0 else x + 5
with tf.Session() as sess:
  x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 1]))
  output = tf.map_fn(my_fn, x)
```

Error:

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use the logical TensorFlow ops to test the value of a tensor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where).

For your example, you could do:

```py
condition = tf.greater(x, 0)
res = tf.where(condition, tf.square(x), x + 5)
```

---

EDIT: move from `tf.select` to `tf.where`

Comment: tf.select changed to tf.where in version 1.0. Googling yields that pretty quickly, but it might be worth noting in this answer, @Olivier. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

`tf.select` is no more working as indicated by this thread as well
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8647

Something that worked for me was `tf.where`

```
condition = tf.greater(x, 0)
res = tf.where(condition, tf.square(x), x + 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

One easiest way to achieve this using [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond)

```
res = tf.cond(tf.greater(x, 0), lambda: tf.square(x), lambda: x + 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `my_fn` has no means of checking the condition `x>0`, since `x` is a `tf.Tensor`, which means that it will be filled with values only if a tensorflow session is started and you request to run a part of the graph that includes `x`. To include if-then logic in the graph itself, you have to use the operations that tensorflow provides, e.g. [`tf.select`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#select).